# creating a rounded bottom border on a card

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a border at the bottom of a card using jetpack compose.

Kind of like this in order to make the card feel like it has a thickness to it.

[image: border bottom]

I did manage to get that working using two cards "stacked" on top of eachother

```kotlin
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .wrapContentSize()
        .padding(5.dp)
        .padding(25.dp)
        .padding(0.dp,0.dp,0.dp,15.dp)) {

        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(180.dp, 200.dp)
                .offset(10.dp, 12.dp),
            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
                defaultElevation = 10.dp
            )
        ) {
        }
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(180.dp, 200.dp)
                .offset(10.dp, 10.dp),
            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
                defaultElevation = 10.dp
            )
        ) {
        }
    }
```

But to me this feels like a pretty hacky solution and something I would like to avoid.
So I wonder if there is any other ways of creating a similar effect?

Comment: There is always the option of importing a vector drawable to represent your card as you like it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try and experiment with `drawBehind` modifier. Stacking of rounded rects is involved too, but it looks much cleaner to me.

Snippet below produces the following result:

[image: Card with thickness]

When you uncomment the line with semi-transparent `backgroundColor`, you can see what is being drawn behind the Card (it is full rounded rect, as you cannot set corners individually on Canvas with this method):

[image: Card with transparent background]

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun CardWithThickness(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val cardHeightDp = 100.dp
    val cornerRadiusDp = 20.dp
    val borderThicknessDp = 2.dp
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = borderThicknessDp)
    ) {
        Card(
            // backgroundColor = Color(0x99999999),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = cornerRadiusDp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(180.dp, cardHeightDp)
                .drawBehind {
                    drawRoundRect(
                        color = Color.Red,
                        topLeft = Offset(0f, (cardHeightDp - 2 * cornerRadiusDp).toPx()),
                        size = this.size.copy(height = (2 * cornerRadiusDp + borderThicknessDp).toPx()),
                        cornerRadius = CornerRadius(cornerRadiusDp.toPx())
                    )
                },
        ) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```